# Display a backend-view in the frontend in a custom Joomla 3.4 component

Tags: php, joomla, backend

I am currently doing the Joomla-Tutorial about how to make custom components: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/

So far, my backend is working fine. What I want to do now is to display the backend view in the frontend, giving a logged in administrator the option to add and edit instances of my component without having to use the backend.

Unfortunately, the part about the frontend updating is not yet written in the tutorial and the corresponding article in the 2.5 documentation is marked as non-optimal.

Is there a "standard" way to display backend views in the frontend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at how the media manager handles it, that will give you a model. It's tricky and not ideal.It might actually be easier just to create a front end view.

Comment: The comment on the 2.5 documentation says "it is possible and recommended to reuse the model and form created during Adding backend actions for front-end editing", what gave me the idea that there would be a very simple solution. In fact if I manage to get the frontent updating working, the same view is no more needed in the backend. I made an approach by basically just "switching" backend and frontend. This gave me issues with the JToolBarHelper which is only available in the backend and there were several "no permission to access the database" errors.

Comment: So just do that. WHat you need to do is register the prefix including the backend path and just use those.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @Elin And how do you handle customing a view? I use a componente that calls a backend view like this: `include(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'views'.DS.'company'.DS.'tmpl'.DS.'edit.php');` but I would like to customize it without loosing anything on component update. So I tried to put the view in the template's html folder (both front-end and back-end) and it doesn't gets that customized version in front-end, but it works on back-end. I think there should be a joomla way to do that, do you know it?

Comment: Don't confuse the view with the layout. The front and back end are two separate applications and you should just get the view layout from the front end even if you are calling the view class (the v in mvc) from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong what you want to do is a front-end filter. You can [follow the Joomla manual](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components), but it's a bit complicated.
Have you tried to create a quick component with [http://www.component-creator.com],[1](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components) you can see how standard code is created. There's an option to create front-end filters.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I did now. I still don't get where the link between the front-end view and the backend-tables and forms is created - is that just done by setting those functions to public? But well as it is working now thats only for further understanding, I know how to implement the functions I need for the frontend and it is working so far.

Comment: Hi! The only link between front-end and back-end is the database. front-end views y back-end views should never be associated in a well coded Joomla website :)

Comment: What I am trying to do is a front-end form to create an article which has an extra section that links some other parts of the page associated to that article. The article itself is about a teacher and the classes that teacher is teachin should be linked in a list below, also a contact form should be included. As my homepage owner does not know much about that, I want to give him an easy option by just entering a description, e-mail and so on in the frondent and select the classes from a list. The article then is created as well as a contact and a menu entry.

Comment: Btw I found out what I was looking for. The getTable in the frontend model is including the backend table :$this->addTablePath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.'/tables'); That is how the table defined in the backend part is accessed.